# Why if i use my service from my controller i am getting an error about the params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have this piece of code, its a service, as a parameter i am sending a hash {"type"=>"apps"}

```
class CampaingService

  def initialize(types:)
   @datas =  types.map { |key, v| "#{key} #{v}" }.join(', ')
  end
end
```

that service i am using in my controller:

```
def verifying

  CampaingService.new.call( types:params[:types] )
```

but i am getting this

```
#<ActionController::Parameters {"type"=>"apps"} permitted: false>
```

i am getting this error

```
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `map' for #<ActionController::Parameters {"type"=>"apps"} permitted: false>
     
           @datas =  types.map { |key, v| "#{key} #{v}" }.join(', ')
                                   ^^^^
       Did you mean?  tap
```

but if i use directly my service

```
types = { type: 'subjects' }
CampaingService.call(types:).result
```

i dont have errors, its working well

**Edit 1:** i made some changes sending types in controller with `to_hash`

```
CampaingService.new.call( types:params[:types].to_hash )
```

right now i am getting this error: ActionController::UnfilteredParameters: unable to convert unpermitted parameters to hash

Comment: you passed your service a hash manually, the controller is passing an ActionController::Parameters object -- not a hash. It does not have a map method. https://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/4.1.7/ActionController/Parameters You can call .to_hash on it to send it to your service.

Comment: @dbugger i am getting this error: ActionController::UnfilteredParameters:
        unable to convert unpermitted parameters to hash

Comment: @dbugger i just edited my question please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to permit the parameters before they can be converted to a hash. Something like this in your controller...

```
def verifying_params
   params.require(:type).permit! #this permits all the parmeters
end
```

then use it in your action method...

```
def verifying

  CampaingService.new.call( types:verifying_params.to_hash )

end
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of saying `@data = @types.map.....` try `@data = types.map.....`

Comment: only it was a typo

Answer (score 0):

Rails relies on only tolerated parameters passing through from the front end to the back end (via the controller).

Usually they're based on objects, in which you require the object name, and allow specific attributes of that object.

For instance:  An object called Taxonomy with various attributes like order, family, subfamily, tribe, subtribe, genus, species, common_name.  Your permitted parameters would look like:

```
params.require(:taxonomy).permit(:order, :family, 
       :subfamily, :tribe, :subtribe, :genus, :species, :common_name)
```

In your case, it doesn't seem like you're passing a whole object, though that would be fine, but if its just the single param, you can permit it alone.

```
params.permit(:type)
```